# Why do I get TypeError when calling function dynamically?

Tags: python

I have code similar to this. In MyModule.py

```
class SomeClass:
    @classmethod
    def SomeMethod(cls, a, b, c):
        return "foo"
```

Then I have another python file:

```
cls = getattr(MyModule, "SomeClass")
method = getattr(cls, "SomeMethod")
args = { "a":1, "b": 2, "c": 3 }
res = method(**args)
print "Result: " + res
print "Result type: " + str(type(res))
```

But I get the following error on the row calling type():

```
TypeError: 'unicode' object is not callable
```

To complicate things, I don't get the error with this minified example. Any ideas on how I can debug this? How can type() generate such an error?

Comment: Do you have a variable named `type` perhaps?

Comment: Have you perhaps assigned something to `str` or `type`? What does `repr(str)` and `repr(type)` give you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a local variable `str` or `type` (or both) that is bound to a unicode value. Remove it, that variable is masking the built-in callable.

You can use `del str` or `del type` to remove that reference, and the built-in can be used again.

Alternatively, use:

```
import __builtin__

print "Result type: " + __builtin__.str(__builtin__.type(res))
```

to be absolutely certain you are using the built-ins instead.

Comment: That was indeed the case. I had a variable named type.